# Replace any number of forward slashes with just two forward slashes

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have am working on angular 2 using type script.
I have a input box on html which takes input and i perform search based on that. User can also enter rest resources as part of search such as employee/getDetail.

I want to replace / with // so that my service does not fail. Also pls note if the user enter employee///////getDetail//////salary even then it should return employee/getDetail/salary

Idea to replace and forward slashes with two , if user enter more than 2 then we should have only 2

Can i escape these in angular ui itself?

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: I would probably handle this in the JS code itself.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: 'aa////////bb/////cc/d'.replace(/\/*/g,'//') does not work :(

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant `'aa////////bb/////cc/d'.replace(/\/+/g,'//')`. This line should convert any slashes to double-slashes only (that is, if there are more than 2, then it will become only 2; if there is 1, it will become 2)

Comment: @AshishShukla there are 2 good answers for your question already, do they solve your problem? If they do, please pick one to mark as the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @flen i am not getting an option to accept your comment as the answer as you answered it first :)

Comment: @AshishShukla thanks for the concern!:) I'm just happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the pattern `/{2,}` with a single forward slash.  This removes the duplication but does not affect instances where only one forward slash was (correctly) being used.

```js
var input = "employee///////getDetail//////salary";
console.log(input.replace(/\/{2,}/g, "/"));
```

If you really want *two* forward slashes in the replacement, then use this:

```
input.replace(/\/+/g, "//")
```

Comment: That works but does not adds an extra / when the input is like "emp/get/salary" that should give emp//get//salary

Comment: @AshishShukla This is a new requirement and is a departure from your original question.  Do you want _one_ or _two_ forward slashes in the final path?

Comment: Thank you. Its not a new requirement but the same was mentioned in the detail as well. Anyways cheers thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular expression for the matching of a forward slash and use the [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace 1 or more forward slashes with 2 forward slashes like in the example below.

```js
var forwardSlash = /\/+/g;
var input = "employee///////getDetail//////salary";
console.log(input.replace(forwardSlash, "//"));
```